# JavaScript for(x in element) strange results

Tags: javascript

Alright, I'm trying to use the basic document.getElementsByTagName function, but each time I do, it brings up results that don't exist. Ie: elements with undefined nodeNames, and things like this. This causes my script to halt, and is giving me quite the trouble.

Here is a sample:

This HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

with this script

```
for(x in document.getElementsByTagName('div'))
  alert(document.getElementsByTagName('div')[x].nodeName);
```

generates this

```
DIV
DIV
DIV
undefined
```

then the script quits.

I cannot locate the issue, and it works like this in all browsers...

Just ask for any other details...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correction: `getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList`, which has numeric indices and a `length` property, thereby making it an `Array`-like object.

Nevertheless, you should just use a simple `for` loop like so:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i = 0, j = els.length; i < j; i++) {
  alert(els[i].nodeName);
```

The reason why you want to use `for` and not `for..in` here is because `for..in` uses inherited properties of the iterated object, so to avoid that you can use `hasOwnProperty`, but in this case where you're only iterating over a numeric indice, I think it's better to use a simple `for` loop over using `for..in` and `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say, but please note that `document.getElementsByTagName` does not return an `Array`.

Comment: `NodeList` is an array-like object, so the original statement still applies. Using `for..in` on an array-like object also enumerates the `length` property and any other property defined in the prototype chain. (current answer is still ok, just wanted to clarify that first bit.)

Comment: Perfect answer. Exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: @gonchuki - Absolutey. 1) This solution is correct; 2) `getElementsByTagName` does not return an `Array`. There's no contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript returns all properties of the object when using for ( in ).  Use .hasOwnProperty to skip inherited properties:

```
var elems = documents.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (x in elems){
    if (elems.hasOwnProperty(x))
        alert(elems[x].nodeName);
}
```

Comment: The collection returned has its own `length` property, and appears to be enumerable (at least in Chrome 10). A `for` loop would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: Sure, if you know it's an array, you can just use an old fashioned for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++).